Script can't find a leaderstat
I'm trying to make a base script for challenges:
-- Rewards for challenges: Easy(25-100), Medium(100-200), Hard(200-450), Difficult(450-700), Challenging(700-1000), Intense(1000-1750), Remorseless(1750+)
-- Remember to make challenges for all realms; It sucks when you get a r9 challenge but u havent even unlocked r5 yet

Gui = game:GetService('StarterGui')
Players = game:GetService('Players')
LeaderStats = Players.LocalPlayer:FindFirstChild('leaderstats')
coins = LeaderStats:FindFirstChild('Coins')
EasyEvent = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Easy.EasyChallengeEvent
EasyReward = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Easy.Reward
MediumEvent = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Medium.MediumChallengeEvent
MediumReward = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Medium.Reward
HardEvent = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Hard.HardChallengeEvent
HardReward = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Hard.Reward
DifficultEvent = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Difficult.DifficultChallengeEvent
DifficultReward = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Difficult.Reward
ChallengingEvent = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Challenging.ChallengingChallengeEvent
ChallengingReward = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Challenging.Reward
IntenseEvent = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Intense.IntenseChallengeEvent
IntenseReward = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Intense.Reward
RemorselessEvent = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Remorseless.RemorselessChallengeEvent
RemorselessReward = Gui.Gui.Menu.ChallengeFrame.Remorseless.Reward
print(coins)

I tried printing out coins leaderstat, I expected it to either print 'Coins' or 'nil', but it didn't print anything.
